# Can this be done without a regular expression?

Tags: c#, php, regex, string, split

I've got a string split, using a regular expression.

```
 Regex.Split(str, @"\s");
```

What does this convert to without regex? reason being I'm porting this to PHP and an SQL function. Unless you can show me the PHP code for the same...

Comment: FYI, everything can be done without regexes.

Comment: You're going from c# to php??  Who does that?

Comment: Can you also show me how to do a similar operation without regular expressions? in any language.

Comment: write a function `SplitOnDelimiters(char[] delimeters, string s)`.  then call it with `SplitOnDelimiters(new[] {' ', '\t', '\n'}, s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
preg_split("/\\s/", str);
```

Comment: Can you show me the SQL code for the same? I'm trying this as an SQL stored function.